# OpenCV: detecting large calibration patterns using findCirclesGrid

Tags: python, opencv, calibration

I'm using OpenCV to detect calibration targets (specifically asymmetric circles, but the question applies to symmetric circles too).

When the number of pixels in a particular circle is small (diameter less than about 30-40 pixels, from experience), findCirclesGrid works fine, but if the diameter is too large None is returned. I've tried creating targets at different sizes (thanks, [calib.io](https://calib.io/pages/camera-calibration-pattern-generator)!), and the overall grid size seems irrelevant, but if each circle is too big, the detection fails.

I assume some calls are made to contours / blob-type functions, and it is these which are failing due to some max size constraint. Is there a way to specify parameters in the contour/blob part of the process without rewriting the entire findCirclesGrid? I'm working in Python, so any fundamental re-write would be inefficient in programming time and run-time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "asymmetric circles" ??

Comment: Asymmetric circle grid pattern is meant. Sorry, I dont know about parameterization possibilities, but you could resize (downsize) the image before detection and scale back the found circle positions afterwards.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.